# Cannot convert unicode to utf-8 in python

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, encode

It must be a trivial task but I can't handle it.
I have json that looks like this.

```
        {'
          city': u'\\u0410\\u0431\\u0430\\u043a\\u0430\\u043d', 
        'language':{
          u'\\u0410\\u043d\\u0433\\u043b\\u0438\\u0439\\u0441\\u043a\\u0438\\u0439': 5608,      
          u'\\u0418\\u0442\\u0430\\u043b\\u044c\\u044f\\u043d\\u0441\\u043a\\u0438\\u0439': 98
        }
    },
```

I'm trying to convert the unicode strings into utf-8.

```
string=u'\u0410\u0431\u0430\u043a\u0430\u043d'
string.encode('utf-8')
```

I've got

```
'\xd0\x90\xd0\xb1\xd0\xb0\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd'
```

Instead of:

```
u'Абакан'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're seeing the `repr` of the byte string, which doesn't try to show the actual characters. Try `print`ing it.

Comment: Your sample JSON is not really JSON. If those are Python values, you have double-encoded `\u` unicode escapes in those unicode strings. Is that really what you have or did you type this out by hand?

Comment: Your `string` sample value is a proper `unicode` object, which you could just directly print (`print string`), and the same applies to the encoded value (`print string.encode('utf8')`). You are getting confused by the *string representation* echoed by the Python interactive interpreter or used to show the contents of containers like a dictionary or a list. Representations are ASCII-safe debugging values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Not printing it.

When you just evaluate a string in Python REPL, you will get its `repr`. This is `'\xd0\x90\xd0\xb1\xd0\xb0\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd'`. When you print it, you will get `Абакан`.

```
print(string.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: that was... silly) Thank you. Even though, I've got another problem when I try to save the json as file I've got 
`u'\\u0410\\u043d\\u0433\\u043b\\u0438\\u0439\\u0441\\u043a\\u0438\\u0439'`

How to convert it into cyrillic letters?

`with open('file_to_save.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(json_var, outfile)'`

Comment: `u'\\u0410\\u043d\\u0433\\u043b\\u0438\\u0439\\u0441\\u043a\\u0438\\u0439'` is not valid JSON. (note the quotes.) `u'"\\u0410\\u043d\\u0433\\u043b\\u0438\\u0439\\u0441\\u043a\\u0438\\u0439"'` is valid JSON. With this latter value, `import json; print(json.loads(x))` prints `Английский`.

Answer (score 1):

As @Amadan said, you just need to print your string.

But why printing string resolves the problem?

The answer is that if you type `string` + <kbd>Enter</kbd> this will lead to display the representation of [`repr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr) the of the object `string`; while running print string (or print (string) in Python 3.x) you will get a human readable string representation -[`str()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str)- of `string`.

```
>>> converted = string.encode('utf8')
>>> converted
'\xd0\x90\xd0\xb1\xd0\xb0\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd'
>>> print converted
Абакан
>>> print repr(converted)
'\xd0\x90\xd0\xb1\xd0\xb0\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd'
>>> print str(converted)
Абакан
>>>
```

Further reading: [Difference between __str__ and __repr__ in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python)

Comment: `str` of string gives the string itself; `print(str(x))` == `print(x)`, and `print(repr(x))` is pretty much the same as `str(x)` in REPL (as `str(x)` will be again displayed using `repr`).